# Adsense based on view port

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, adsense

I am about to launch a responsive website which will have Adsense in it. Since the website is responsive; I am expecting to have different set of Adsense banners to address the correct banner according to screen size.

What is the best approach taken these days to achieve this? Does it rely on Javascript, or simply on CSS like the idea behind responsive (for example resizing the banner's size to fit in the content area).

Lastly, does Adsense have a feature yet to build the same banner spot for several devices, and deliver the correct banner based on the view port?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use Google's responsive ads.

Essentially you set the size to "responsive" while creating the ad unit.
All the rest is done by Google themselves provided the parent has a width that you set (via css and/or media queries).

They adapt themselves to the width of their parent at load time. So if you resize they get too small/too big — but real world uses are OK-ish.

Best to get the how-to create them from [Google themselves](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en&utm_source=aso&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_).

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the media Query For resizing the banner's size.

For this you have to refer this link :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

See the demo here using media query : http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: You're missing the question again. I am not speaking about regular banners here, I am taking about AdSense banners.